# How to hide a parent div if children contains a certain text/string?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="row word-style table-border">
 <a href="#" target="_blank">
 <div class="col-md-1 underlined">00184799</div>
        </a>

    <div class="col-md-1">  
        Salesforce Case 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
     Machine Down 
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-1">
        Machine Down
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        Internal Request
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to hide the whole entire div if ever the text Internal Request is present.

Comment: which div you want to hide?

Comment: the whole <div class="row word-style table-border"> @gokublack

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DOM API for this,

```
$containers = document.querySelectorAll("div.row.word-style.table-border");

for($container of $containers) {
  if ($container.innerText.includes('Internal Request')) {
    $container.style.display = "none" ;
  }
}
```

[check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/CharlesRajendran/n4jeqwLc/18/)

Comment: it works on jsfiddle, but it isnt working on my html :( Am I missing something?

Comment: is it possible to show me the HTML file? I hope you put the js code inside `<script>` tag right?

Comment: It should be like this, https://jsfiddle.net/CharlesRajendran/n4jeqwLc/12/

Comment: it works only on the first div that has that class. it has a series of rows @gokublack

Comment: I updated the answer, pls update the question, mentioning the multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you:

```
$('.row .col-md-1').each(function(index,col){
    if($(col).text() == 'Internal Request'){
       $(col).hide();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to peel this apple. Here's one:

```js
var row=document.querySelector(".row");
var children = row.childNodes

children.forEach(c=>{
  if(c.innerHTML&&c.innerHTML.indexOf("Internal Request") !== -1) {
    row.className+=" hidden"
}
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row word-style table-border">
 <a href="#" target="_blank">
 <div class="col-md-1 underlined">00184799</div>
        </a>

    <div class="col-md-1">  
        Salesforce Case 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
     Machine Down 
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-1">
        Machine Down
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        Internal Request
    </div>

</div>
```